androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.2.0-alpha01 not working in fragment
I am developng a android app with swip to refresh functinality. I am using androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.2.0-alpha01 dependency of google.
   ` <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           tools:listitem="@layout/item_post"
           tools:itemCount="5"/>


    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>`

its working in avtivty but not working in fragmant showing blank only.
